# Control for custom grid data

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5

I am trying to find a suitable component for use in a .NET 4.5 WPF project. If possible, the project should benefit from caliburn.micro binding convention.

The raw data consists of an array of complex objects (our own classes) indexed by their metadata (subject, date, hour).

The visual representation should be like the following:

[image]

The visual representation should be slightly 3D. The strongly bordered are represents one single week of one single subject. Inside that area, each row is a day and each column is a particular hour inside that day.

The cells should be selectable, either individually (like on left click), continuously (Shift key) or randomly (Ctrl key). The control needs to support context menus and redrawing cells when the complex type's properties changes.

There is no need for moving columns, rows, ability to add rows or columns by the user, nor to edit cell values in-line.

I have tried to utilize DataGrid, but it does not fit the requirements, neither I could find any other useful control, nor any base type to start with.

Do you have a suggestion how to get it? What control to use, if not trivial, how to set the control to work as required etc.

Comment: You can easily do this with some nested `ItemsControl`s, however you might hit performance problems depending on the number of columns you need. Otherwise you'll have to implement your own `VirtualizingGrid` I guess.

Comment: Even handling selecting/deselecting (multiple) cells is easy with nested ItemsControl?

There will be just few thousands of cells. All cells are being available from the beginning, or they will be added on a user quest in batches. Loading time of a second or two is acceptable.

Comment: Create a proper ViewModel and everything will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to shell out some money to use a third party tool. I have used a product suite called Syncfusion, specifically their charts WPF controls. They have good Demos on their website and their customer service is good from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

This site have a lot of controls. You can go to it search your control...
I see a dataGrid control on this site.
**www.telerik.com**

**http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/gridview.aspx**